# Cannot throw exception without getting the error: "Not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, return-path

Im currently trying to make a new function inside of a class (in C#) and inside I have

```
public static Planet searchByName(String nameIn)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < planetList.Count; i++)
        {
            Planet returnPlanet = null;
            if (planetList.ElementAt(i).name == nameIn)
            {
                returnPlanet = planetList.ElementAt(i);
            }
            if (returnPlanet == null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException(String.Format("Planet with name {0} does not exist", nameIn));
            }
            return returnPlanet;
        }
    }
```

Im not sure how to throw the Exception and get it to return a value (or at least get rid of the current error)

Edit: Ah, I see, as many of you pointed out, the loop I have has a possibility of not running (although in my code it would always run, but I doubt the Compiler would know that)

Comment: Isn't it working? You seem to be doing almost right thing

Comment: @TalhaIrfan the issue is that there is no `return` in the situation that the `for` condition is false.

Comment: And why not make return variable as Planet returnPlanet = new Planet(); ?

Answer (score 2):

What would happen if the `planetList` had no members?  The loop would never enter and nothing would be returned.

You need to return something if this is the case.  Simply returning null would work:

```
public static Planet searchByName(String nameIn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < planetList.Count; i++)
    {
        Planet returnPlanet = null;
        if (planetList.ElementAt(i).name == nameIn)
        {
            returnPlanet = planetList.ElementAt(i);
        }
        if (returnPlanet == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException(String.Format("Planet with name {0} does not exist", nameIn));
        }
        return returnPlanet;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, if you look closer at your code you'll find that on the first iteration the planet will either be found or an exception will be thrown, those are the only two options.  You should only throw an exception if the entire list has been checked, which would looks like this:

```
public static Planet searchByName(String nameIn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < planetList.Count; i++)
    {
        Planet planet = planetList.ElementAt(i);
        if (nameIn == planet.name)
            return planet;
    }
    throw new System.ArgumentException(String.Format("Planet with name {0} does not exist", nameIn));
}
```

You could also achieve the same goal with LINQ, which looks much nicer:

```
public static Planet searchByName(string name)
{
    return planetList.FirstOrDefault(planet => planet.name == name);
}
```

Comment: Its better if he creates the Planet using default constructor and creates it before the loop body and then returns that variable. What do you say?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I dont think that's better, the planet with that name doesn't exist.  If that was the intention I would name the method `findOrCreatePlanet(string name)`

Comment: I got you!! Your LINQ answer is really cool approach. Thanks for enlightening here.

Answer (score 1):

If your `for` loop condition (`i < planetList.Count`) is false, the `for` loop won't be run. You need to `return` something if the `for` isn't run.

```
public static Planet searchByName(String nameIn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < planetList.Count; i++)
    {
        . . .
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Exactly! I realized it soon after as well

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `Planet` with a `name` field that matches `nameIn`.

The pseudocode for this would be something like

```
for every planet in the list of planets
    if planet's name == nameIn
        return plant
after the for loop, if no matching planet was found, throw an exception
```

Here's your code following my pseudocode

```
public static Planet searchByName(String nameIn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < planetList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (planetList.ElementAt(i).name == nameIn)
        {
            return planetList.ElementAt(i);
        }
    }
    throw new System.ArgumentException(String.Format("Planet with name {0} does not exist", nameIn));
}
```

Here's how I would write it with a for-each loop:

```
public static Planet searchByName(String nameIn)
{
    for (var planet in planetList)
    {
        if (planet.name == nameIn)
        {
            return planet;
        }
    }
    throw new System.ArgumentException(String.Format("Planet with name {0} does not exist", nameIn));
}
```

Here's how I would write it with LINQ:

```
public static Planet searchByName(String nameIn)
{
    Planet planet = planetList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == nameIn);
    if (planet != null)
    {
        return planet;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException(String.Format("Planet with name {0} does not exist", nameIn))
    }
}
```